# Puppeteer.NET: Can't autopopulate field

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I am a just starting out with Puppeteer.NET, and i can't get it to autofill a login page.
The HTML for the web site looks like this:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="row">
   <div class="column section col-md-8">
    <div class="loginForm">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" width="300">
        <br /><br /><br />
        <div style="color: #454550; font-family: 'Neuzeit Grotesk'; font-size: 16px; ">
            Welcome back
        </div>
            <br />
        <form action="/login?app=LM&var=au" method="POST" name="login-form" id="login-form">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="BQ2YoR3d-5P__6b5HfqlVOjv8YgTypKV92XA" />
            
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="text" name="username" id="login-form-username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="password" name="password" id="login-form-password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div style="color: #808083; margin-top: 30px; font-family: 'Roboto2';">
            <a href="https:">Trouble logging in?</a>
            <img src="images/grey_line.svg" width="300">
            <a href="https://">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; width:400px;">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>  
    <div class="column section col-md-4">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" src="https://"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get it to fill in the login and password fields, and press the login button.
I am doing it as:

```
            var extra = new PuppeteerExtra();
            var stealth = new StealthPlugin();
            
            LaunchOptions options = new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
                ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            };

            Browser browser = extra.Use(stealth).LaunchAsync(options).Result;
            string content = null;
            using (Page page = browser.NewPageAsync().Result)
            {
                // do login screen
                page.GoToAsync(url);
                page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
                page.WaitForSelectorAsync("username");
                page.FocusAsync("username");
                page.Keyboard.TypeAsync(login);
                page.WaitForSelectorAsync("password");
                page.FocusAsync("password");
                page.Keyboard.TypeAsync(password);
                page.ClickAsync("submit");
                page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
                content = page.GetContentAsync().Result;
            }
```

I have tried changing the "username" to "#username" and some other variations, but nothing gets filled in. Ultimately, all I want to to login and then go to a specific page, and have a dump of the resultant HTML.
Also is there a easy way to just a text dump of the resultant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selectors `#login-form-username` and `#login-form-password`, those are the IDs.

Comment: HI thanks for that.. i got it to be able to enter the login and password. but the problem now is that i cant get the ClickAsync() click to work. I tried #submit, #login-form-submit and several others for the selector. what would the selector for the login button be as there is no ID name?